# How to make hang effect in Angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a component `mat-list-item`. How to make the hover effect appear when  hover over it.

```
<mat-list-item style="cursor:pointer" *ngFor="let sprWellplatform of sprWellplatforms" (click)="onSelectSprWellplatform(sprWellplatform)">
  <h4 mat-line>{{sprWellplatform.name}}</h4> 
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
</mat-list-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach :** 

 
You can use the css `hover` directly to get the hover working on the items.

 Class `mat-list-item` is added to your `mat-list-item` tag by Angular. 
So, apply `hover`` on this class as following :

```
.mat-list-item:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.54);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

[Only MatList Demo](https://angular-jewgan.stackblitz.io)

**Demo with proper code :** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jewgan?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Please comment, if not helpful.

Comment: @user10493107  please upvote the answer as its helpful, as upvoting is good for the people who look for answers. Thank you.